# iOS: setter in an object class with external parameter

Tags: ios, oop, swift, nsobject

I have this object class

```
class City {

    var name:String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var video:String?
    var description:String?
    var image_array:NSArray?
}
```

in this class there is a property called `image_array`, and I want to assign it an `NSArray` as you can read.
But in this case I have to pass at this property a `String` that I should transform into an array

example:

```
The string is "img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg"
```

then I use

```
let fullNameArray = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

and I obtain an `NSArray`

So what's the way to pass this `String` to the setter for `image_array` inside `City` object?
Then inside the setter to transform it into an array... I hope that it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't, you need to either 1. transform it into an array and then pass it, or 2. add a different method which takes a string, transforms it and then calls the array setter.

Option 1. is better as it maintains a sane interface and doesn't pollute the class interface with crud from other classes.

Comment: mmm ok then you thing that the best solution is to don't touch the structure object... ok

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way in order to write string from array use

```
var myString:String = array.description.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]"))
```

and to get array back from string

```
var array:[String] = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(", ") //dont forget space character
```